# Enviar por Http POST resultado de una busqueda en Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

le realizo una consulta
estoy tratando de pasar una seleccion que hago con una table de los componente de primeng pero cuando envio por post me envia el objeto sin el array; en donde podria estar el error

a.page.http

```
            <p-button (click)= "procesar()" icon="pi pi-check" styleClass="ui-button-danger" iconPos="right" label="Procesar" style="margin: 20px"></p-button>
          </div>

        </div>

<h3 class="first">Listado de Transacciones</h3>
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="elementos" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selected" dataKey="orderid">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
        <div style="text-align: left">
            Seleccion : {{selected ? selected.orderid + ' - ' + selected.referencia + ' - ' + selected.monto + ' - '
            + selected.operacion + ' - '+ selected.estado + ' - '+ selected.fechagenerada + ' - '
            + selected.fechapagada + ' - ' + selected.procesado: ' - '}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

a.page.ts
luego de seleccionar en la table en httl va a procesar() alli llama al servicio

```
      this._fecha_desde = formatDate(new Date(this.fecha_desde), 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'es-Ar');
      this._fecha_hasta = formatDate(new Date(this.fecha_hasta), 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'es-Ar');
      let tx=this.transactionCupones;
      console.log(this._fecha_desde);
      console.log(this._fecha_hasta);
      console.log(this.selected);

      try {

        this.transactionsService.buscarProcesar(this._fecha_desde, this._fecha_hasta, this.selected)

        .subscribe(resp => {
          this.elementos=resp;
            console.log(resp);

        },
        error => { // error path
            console.log(error);

         });
    } catch (error) {

    }
  }
```

a.service.ts
este es el servicio que llamo via post

```
buscarProcesar(fecha_desde: string, fecha_hasta: string, tx:transactionCupons):Observable<transactionCupons[]>{
  const url = `${this.baseURL}/procesar/desde/${fecha_desde}/hasta/${fecha_hasta}`
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    });


    console.log(fecha_hasta)
    console.log(fecha_desde)

  return this.http
  .post<transactionCupons[]>(url,tx)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this._handleErrors)
  );

}
```

y cuando envio el post, me da el siguiente error;

[image: sale este error]

[image: el body]
[image: no toma el []]
gracias, no se donde pueda estar el error

Comment: Tienes un [HTTP Status code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400), lo que significa que el error viene del servidor, no del cliente.

Comment: Hola. Como comenta @VRoxa tu problema es el backend. Checa si [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array) resuelve tu problema

Comment: y si el back, recibe en array, como podria ajustar el front, gracias y saludos